# Change SQL Query to CakePHP Query

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp

The given below is the query that I wanted to convert in Cakephp, Can someone help me out.

```
SELECT S.name, (sum(El.amount) - (EE.total - EE.Returned_equipment)) As "Leftover", EE.equipment_id, sum(EL.amount), EQ.type 
From States S 
Inner Join events EV ON S.id = EV.state_id 
Inner Join equipment_events EE ON EE.event_id = EV.id 
Inner Join equipment_locations EL On EL.equipment_id = EE.equipment_id 
Inner Join equipment EQ On EQ.id = EE.equipment_id 
Inner Join events E2 ON E2.location_id = EL.location_id
Inner Join locations L On L.state_id = S.id
Where EE.Bool_value = "Open" Group BY EE.equipment_id, S.name
```

Comment: Please only tag your question with the tags that are actually relevant, ie tag them with the CakePHP version that you are actually using, 2.x and 3.x are very different. Also please always show what you've already tried, and with what part of the problem you are struggling specifically (programming wise)!

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP 3 Try something like this:

```
    use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

    $query = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('S', ['table' => 'States'])->find();
    
    $sumElAmount = $query->func()->sum('El.amount');
    
    $query->select(['S.name']);
    $query->select(['Leftover' => $sumElAmount - 'EE.total - EE.Returned_equipment']);
    $query->select(['EE.equipment_id']);
    $query->select([$sumElAmount]);
    $query->select(['EQ.type']);
    $query->where(['EE.Bool_value' => 'Open']);
    $query->join([
        'EV' => [
            'table' => 'events',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => ['S.id = EV.state_id'],
        ],
        // add more inner joins
    ]);
    $query->group(['EE.equipment_id', 'S.name']);

    $this->set('results', $query);
```

And read:

https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/query-builder.html